# Sql Developer opens SQL Worksheet in wrong Connection Window

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I apparently pressed something by accident and after it if I right click in the *Connections* window on a connection
and choose *Open Sql Worksheet*, it opens, but not in the right (editor) window but in the same window where the connections are.

[image]

I must take the new Worksheet drag it to the right window to be able to use it (as I keep the Connection window narrow).

How can I restor the original behaivior, that the new sheet is opened in the right window?

Recherche with "Sql Developer opens SQL Worksheet in wrong Connection Window" provided no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drag the worksheet out of the docked panel next to your connections to where it belongs.

Or, Window - Reset Windows to Factory Settings.

The Window menu bar task will reset the desktop layout for the application.

Comment: Splendid Jeff, *reset to factory settings* helped perfectly!